# Inserting data in to database using jquery/ajax,i am not getting ant error but values not inserting in to the database

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, codeigniter

**Inserting data in to database using jquery/ajax,i am not getting ant error but values not inserting in to the database using codeigniter,any mistake i done means please suggest me**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#personal-info").click(function () {
                e.preventDefault();
                var message = $("#message").val();
                //  var password= $("#password").val();


                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/Profile_cntrl/buyer_communication",
                    data: {message: message},
                    success: function (data)
                    {
                        alert('Successfully inserted');
                    },
                    error: function ()
                    {
                        alert('fail');
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

**form**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" id="personal-info"  role="form" action="#"> 
                            <div class="panel-footer">
                                <div class="input-group">

                                    <input type ="hidden" name="suppid" id="suppid" value="<?php echo $row->supplier_id; ?>" class="form-control" />
                                    <input type ="hidden" name="proid" id="proid" value="<?php echo $row->product_id; ?>" class="form-control" />
                                    <input type ="hidden" name="custid" id="custid" value="<?php echo $row->Customer_id; ?>" class="form-control" />



                                    <input id="messagee" name="message" type="text" class="form-control input-sm chat_input" placeholder="Write your message here..." />
                                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="submit-p" name="submit-p">Send</button>
                                        <!--<input type="submit" name="submit-p" id="submit-p" value="send" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" >-->
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

**controller**

```
public function buyer_communication() {

    $supp_id = $this->input->post('suppid');
    $product_id = $this->input->post('proid');
    $cust_id = $this->input->post('custid');



    $result1 = $this->Profile_model->fetch_Data($product_id);


    $Userid = $this->session->userdata('id');
    $result3 = $this->session->userdata('tt');
    $data4 = array(
        'message' => $this->input->post('message'),
        'supplier_id' => $supp_id,
        'product_id' => $product_id,
        'Customer_id' => $cust_id,
        'From' => $result3,
    );

    $this->Profile_model->buyer_insert($data4);

    redirect('welcome/buyermessageview?id=' . $product_id);
}
```

**Model**

```
function buyer_insert($data4) {
        $this->db->insert('communication', $data4);
        return ($this->db->affected_rows() != 1) ? false : true;
    }
```

Comment: <?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/Profile_cntrl/buyer_communication put this in your action and see if the data goes to the db ....youll know your errors at least and can rectify them

Comment: on a side note comment out the ajax part so it performs a regular post

Answer (score 3):

**modified script**

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#personal-info").submit(function(e){
               e.preventDefault();


               var suppid = $("#suppid").val();
               var proid = $("#proid").val();
               var custid = $("#custid").val();
                var message = $("#message").val();

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/Profile_cntrl/buyer_communication",
                    data: {suppid:suppid,proid:proid,custid:custid,message:message},
                    success:function(data)
                    {
                        alert('SUCCESS!!');
                    },
                    error:function()
                    {
                        alert('fail');
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

**controller**
public function buyer_communication() {

```
    $result1 = $this->Profile_model->fetch_Data($product_id);


    $Userid = $this->session->userdata('id');
    $result3 = $this->session->userdata('tt');
    $data4 = array(
        'message' => $this->input->post('message'),
        'supplier_id' => $this->input->post('suppid'),
        'product_id' => $this->input->post('proid'),
        'Customer_id' => $this->input->post('custid'),
        'From' => $result3,
    );

    $this->Profile_model->buyer_insert($data4);

    redirect('welcome/buyermessageview?id=' . $product_id);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#personal-info").click(function () {
    e.preventDefault();
```

is not preventing the default postback because you didn't define `e`. Almost certainly your page is posting back rather than using ajax, because the script never has chance to run. Try:

```
$("#personal-info").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
```

Secondly, you aren't passing all the data to your server from the form. You only send "message", but it's clear the server requires other fields. You can send all your form fields automatically by putting this as the "data" field in your ajax call:

```
data: $(this).serialize()
```

You also said "I am not getting any error", but this is unlikely. If you checked your browser console (in the Developer Tools, by pressing F12 in most browsers) you would probably have seen the error "e is not defined" or similar, telling you that you had forgotten to define the variable.

Comment: sorry your code is not working..error message showing like Fail

Comment: that means it _is_ now working as per the solution above - now the ajax call is running, but it is failing for some reason. You need to output the full error message. Again check your console / network tools. You can also get jQuery to give the error by defining your "error" callback with the proper parameters, as per the documentation at http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ We need to know the status code and error message being generated.

Comment: P.S. You send this data `data: {message: message}` to the server, but it looks like the method requires some other fields from the form e.g. suppid, proid, custid which you are not sending. Also at the end of the PHP you do a redirect, but ajax cannot handle redirects because it's within the context of one page, not a postback. You need to return a message or some data directly.

Comment: give me one simple example i cannot understand

Comment: I made two comments. Which bit don't you understand?  how to discover the error? Or how to send the other fields in the ajax request?