# Without refresh the page how to display the values from database using ajax/jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, codeigniter

After inserting data into the database through jQuery/ajax, while fetching values from database without refresh the page how to display the database values using codeigniter?

[image: display form]

This is my code:

Script:

```
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#personal-info").submit(function(e){
               e.preventDefault();
               var suppid = $("#suppid").val();
               var proid = $("#proid").val();
               var custid = $("#custid").val();
                var message = $("#message").val();

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/Profile_cntrl/buyer_communication",
                    data: {suppid:suppid,proid:proid,custid:custid,message:message},
                    success:function(data)
                    {
                        alert('SUCCESS!!');
                    },
                    error:function()
                    {
                        alert('fail');
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Controller:

```
public function buyer_communication() {

        $result1 = $this->Profile_model->fetch_Data($product_id);


        $Userid = $this->session->userdata('id');
        $result3 = $this->session->userdata('tt');
        $data4 = array(
            'message' => $this->input->post('message'),
            'supplier_id' => $this->input->post('suppid'),
            'product_id' => $this->input->post('proid'),
            'Customer_id' => $this->input->post('custid'),
            'From' => $result3,
        );

        $this->Profile_model->buyer_insert($data4);

        redirect('welcome/buyermessageview?id=' . $product_id);
    }
```

Model:

```
function buyer_insert($data4) {
        $this->db->insert('communication', $data4);
        return ($this->db->affected_rows() != 1) ? false : true;
    }
```

Form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" id="personal-info"  role="form" action="#"> 
                            <div class="panel-footer">
                                <div class="input-group">

                                    <input type ="hidden" name="suppid" id="suppid" value="<?php echo $row->supplier_id; ?>" class="form-control" />
                                    <input type ="hidden" name="proid" id="proid" value="<?php echo $row->product_id; ?>" class="form-control" />
                                    <input type ="hidden" name="custid" id="custid" value="<?php echo $row->Customer_id; ?>" class="form-control" />



                                    <input id="message" name="message" type="text" class="form-control input-sm chat_input" placeholder="Write your message here..." />
                                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="submit-p" name="submit-p">Send</button>
                                        <!--<input type="submit" name="submit-p" id="submit-p" value="send" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" >-->
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44305553/inserting-data-in-to-database-using-jquery-ajax-i-am-not-getting-ant-error-but-v/44305849 are you two working on the same thing, by any chance? Keep it to one question on the same issue, preferably. And also please ask your friend to accept the other answer, since it solved the original problem. Anyway, you haven't described this properly. What's going wrong with your code? At which point does it fail? What errors have you got, if any? What behaviour is wrong?

Comment: P.S. Why, in the ajax, are you manually extracting the values from the form fields, when you could just serialise the whole form? `data: $(this).serialize()` should work instead of all those repetitive variable declarations. https://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: after insert values to database while fetching values from database without refresh the page values should be display in form.

Comment: form code also i added just once refer and suggest me

Comment: @Maruthi Prasad here is the `CRUD` click on the links below  [link 1](https://ibb.co/fUFg5v)   ,  [link 2](https://ibb.co/i1F3JF) , [link 3](https://ibb.co/mRZVyF)  in codeigniter. tell me is this what you want

Comment: @PavanBaddi link 3,above i shown one image,in text field i enter some text and  click the send button,without refresh the page enter message should be display in that page only.

Comment: @PavanBaddi are you got my problem

Comment: @PavanBaddi  i want to redirect the above shown image page(buyermessageview)  in ajax success message

Comment: @Maruthi Prasad here is the screen shots  [link](https://ibb.co/czQykv) . `NOTE: this does not include the session vars it is just a small example`. tell me is this what you wanted

Comment: @PavanBaddi exactly like that i want

Comment: @Maruthi Prasad but when you press the send btn it does not refresh but loads the data through ajax

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145687/discussion-between-maruthi-prasad-and-pavan-baddi).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Maruthi Prasad here is the code.. [IN CODE IGNITER]

HTML view code with jquery script 
views\profile_view.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div id="load_data">

      </div>

      <form method="post" id="personal-info">
            <input id="message" name="message" type="text" class="form-control input-sm chat_input" placeholder="Write your message here..." />
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="submit-p" name="submit-p">Send</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    loaddata();

    data_submit();
});

function loaddata(){
    $.getJSON('<?php echo base_url();?>'+'index.php/Profile_cntrl/get_data',function(data){
        for(var i in data){
            var show = '<div>';
            show += '<h5 style="background:#ccc;padding:10px;border-radius:10px;">'+data[i].message+'</h5>';
            show += '</div>';

            $("#load_data").append(show);
        }
    });
}

function data_submit(){
    $("#personal-info").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var formdata = $(this).serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'<?php echo base_url();?>'+'index.php/Profile_cntrl/insert_data',
            data:formdata,
            success:function(data){
                var res = JSON.parse(data);

                if(res.Status == 'true'){
                    //console.log(res.report);
                    $("#load_data").empty();
                    loaddata()
                }else{
                    alert(res.report);
                }
            }
        }); 
    });
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

CONTROLLER CODE:
controllers\Profile_cntrl.php

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
class Profile_cntrl extends CI_Controller {
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->model('profile_model');
        $this->load->helper(array('url','html','form'));
    }


    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('profile_view');
    }

    public function get_data(){
        $query = $this->profile_model->buyer_communication();

        echo json_encode($query);
    }

    public function insert_data(){
        $arr = array(
            'message'=>$this->input->post('message')
        );

        $sql = $this->profile_model->buyer_insert($arr);

        $op = "data insert id :".$this->db->insert_id();

        if($sql == true){
            $reponse = array(
                'Status'=>'true',
                'report'=>$op
            );
            echo json_encode($reponse);
        }
        else
        {
            $op = "Failed to insert data";

            $reponse = array(
                'Status'=>'false',
                'report'=>$op
            );
            echo json_encode($reponse);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Model code: 
models\Profile_model.php

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Profile_model extends CI_model {

    public function buyer_communication(){
        $sql = $this->db->get('communication');
        $sql = $sql->result_array();
        return $sql;
    }

    public function buyer_insert($arr){
        return $query = $this->db->insert('communication',$arr);
    }
}
?>
```

### Feel free to ask questions