# Content fetch in main page from another page from database through ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have written this code but it didn't work. I have searched so much but those code are not properly work. what should I do? I want to fetch data without refreshing whole page.

I have looked at this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44309000/without-refresh-the-page-how-to-display-the-values-from-database-using-ajax-jque).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#pair_form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var devicename = $("#devicename").val();
    var id = $("#id").val();
    var latitude = $("#latitude").val();
    var longitude = $("#longitude").val();
    var ignition = $("#ignition").val();
    var Arming = $("#Arming").val();

    function showData() {
      $.ajax({
        url: 'http://example.com/ddd/cfg.php',
        method: 'get',
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function(response) {
          $('#result').html(response)
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: What is happening? What error does your console show you? Your code doesnt look wrong, but as I can see, you are not calling `showData()` even. Either call it or remove the function.

Comment: Please update your question. You had a link that was invisible and the code is not valid. Does the other site allow CORS?